# How to enable resource dictionary diagnostics in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, trace, diagnostics, staticresource

I'm tracking an instance of non-existing resource in WPF. What I'm given is an `InvalidOperationException` informing, that `UnsetValue` is not a proper value for `Background` property. However, I don't know, what is the missing resource key or where this setter resides.

I see in WPF sources, that [StaticResource markup extension](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/StaticResourceExtension.cs,109782a9ade5f8b3) uses an internal WPF class called `ResourceDictionaryDiagnostics` to log events regarding resource lookup (see eg. lines 137,152).

Is there a way to enable this diagnostic and capture some information about failed resource lookups?